# Get values in XML response in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am using a GET request to get an XML response from a web service.  I'm attempting to parse the response and display a portion of it in a VBA form. The VBA components I think I have a good handle on but the XML syntax is giving me quite a bit of problems.  This is the sub I have in VBA so far:

```
Sub GetCANSIM()
Dim XMLRequest As New XMLHTTP
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim point As IXMLDOMNode
Dim value As Variant
Dim lngYear As Long

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

XMLRequest.Open "GET", "someURL", False
XMLRequest.send

While XMLRequest.Status <> 200
    DoEvents
Wend

If Not objXML.LoadXML(XMLRequest.responseText) Then
    Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
End If

End Sub
```

I am using the Microsoft XML V6.0 reference.

The XML response is quite large but this is the format of it:

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="CANSIM">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Date" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Year" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Month" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="BondYield_LongTerm_Gov" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="BondYield_LongTerm_Prov" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="BondYield_LongTerm_Corp" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="B14070" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="B14072" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="B14081" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="B14045" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Rolling12MonthAvg" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="B14055" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram>
<NewDataSet>
<CANSIM diffgr:id="CANSIM1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<ID>462</ID>
<Date>2006-06-01T00:00:00-04:00</Date>
<Year>2006</Year>
<Month>6</Month>
<BondYield_LongTerm_Gov>0.0469</BondYield_LongTerm_Gov>
<BondYield_LongTerm_Prov>0.0518</BondYield_LongTerm_Prov>
<BondYield_LongTerm_Corp>0.0581</BondYield_LongTerm_Corp>
<B14070>0.0458</B14070>
<B14072>0.0467</B14072>
<B14081>0.019</B14081>
<B14045>0.0318</B14045>
<Rolling12MonthAvg>0.026425</Rolling12MonthAvg>
<B14055>0.0328</B14055>
</CANSIM>
<CANSIM diffgr:id="CANSIM2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
<ID>463</ID><Date>2006-07-01T00:00:00-04:00</Date><Year>2006</Year><Month>7</Month>
<BondYield_LongTerm_Gov>0.0446</BondYield_LongTerm_Gov>  
<BondYield_LongTerm_Prov>0.0496</BondYield_LongTerm_Prov>
<BondYield_LongTerm_Corp>0.056</BondYield_LongTerm_Corp>
<B14070>0.0431</B14070>
<B14072>0.0445</B14072>
<B14081>0.018</B14081>
<B14045>0.0318</B14045>
<Rolling12MonthAvg>0.027216666667</Rolling12MonthAvg>
<B14055>0.0328</B14055>
</CANSIM>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

I'd like to grab the last 60 months of the "B14045" rate and the "Rolling12MonthAvg" for the 12th month of the last 5 years.

The values are all in order so I am thinking I should be able to "find" or "goto" the starting month (60 months ago) by using the "Month" and "Year" attributes and then reading the B14045 rate in an incrementing loop.

But I don't know the syntax for finding the node(?) I want and then increment forward.  I've tried reading some help files and other topics but I can't seem to make heads or tails of it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the XML syntax by using: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

```
Sub GetCANSIM()
Dim XMLRequest As New XMLHTTP
Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim objNodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim objNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim objElement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim strPath As String
Dim lngYear As Long

Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

XMLRequest.Open "GET", "someURL",False
XMLRequest.send

While XMLRequest.Status <> 200
    DoEvents
Wend

If Not objXML.LoadXML(XMLRequest.responseText) Then
    Err.Raise objXML.parseError.ErrorCode, , objXML.parseError.reason
End If

objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

lngYear = year(Now()) - 8

'Select all the B14045 elements of the CANSIM elements which are within 5 years
strPath = "//CANSIM[Year>" & lngYear & "]/B14045"

Set objNodeList = objXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(strPath)

End Sub
```